# Get Access Token From Google Drive API by GoogleAuthUtil in Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-android-api

I got a weird problem in using GoogleAuthUtil when accessing the Google Drive API.

Following is my code,

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        String accountName = params[0];
        //String scopes = "oauth2:profile email"; // This can work !
        String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:7666010xxxxx-dm0d37oxxxxxxxih8k5sm5g7tajetubk.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
        String token = null;
        try{
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(excpTAG, "IO Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e){
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        }
        catch (GoogleAuthException e)
        {
            Log.e(excpTAG, "GoogleAuthException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }
```

In my empirical test, I can acquire the access token for user's Google profile/email by setting the scopes as

```
String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
```

However, when I want to access user's Google Drive, I followed the instructions in development document

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

and set the scopes as

```
String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:766601xxxxxx-dm0dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7tajetubk.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
```

When the app executed, the Log cat in Android-Studio always mentioned that the exception event GoogleAuthException occured, and the event message is 'Unknown'.

What is the correct way to get the access token for Google Drive in Android? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689858/newly-released-authentication-with-google-play-services-problems-with-getting

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the `"oauth2:" + DriveScopes.Drive` as my scopes, and still got the same error message.

Comment: It should work with a regular scope `oauth2:blabla/drive.file` and it should be a problem with the scope.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried it, and the result is the same, "Unknown". I also checked if I got a typo, but the error message is "INVALID_SCOPE" when scope has a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer !

The main cause of this problem should be the inconsistency of `PACKAGE NAME`  and `CERTIFICATE FINGERPRINT (SHA1)` between **Google API Console** and **Android-Studio**

The inconsistency will cause the authorization exception errors, in certain scopes.

When `PACKAGE NAME`  and `CERTIFICATE FINGERPRINT (SHA1)` in **Android-Studio** don't coincide with those in **Google API Console**, the Google API would not simply reject all the requests. Some scopes like `DriveScopes.Drive` triggered the exception error, while others like `oauth2:profile email` doesn't.

In this case, the exception error also return the `Unknown` message, misdirecting us to fixing the issues aroused by certain scopes.